# Django 2.0 URLs: Configuring urls.py file

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I am a beginner and I have problems with urls,

I have a project, in the project i've created an application called "contacts", in the application, I created a folder "views", in this folder i have a file  "index.py"

The contents of my urls.py file is as follows:

```
#cat urls.py
"""pacha URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please 
see:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.urls import *  
from django.contrib import *   

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^index$', include('contacts.urls')),
    re_path(r'^$', contacts.views.index.page),
]
```

When I run `./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080`
I get this error :

```
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import  
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load  
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked  
ImportError: No module named 'contacts.views.index.page';   
'contacts.views.index' is not a package
```

Thanks !!

Comment: try replacing contacts.views.index.page by contacts.views.index

Comment: also you might need to import contacts at the top

Comment: What are the contents of index.py?

Comment: This code wouldn't give that error, because you haven't imported that file at all. Please show the full code.

Comment: @HarshitSeksaria here's the content of index.py: from django.shortcuts import render

Comment: @AshishAcharya when i try to import contacts i get this error:     from . import contacts
ImportError: cannot import name 'contacts'

Comment: @yacine.b have you added your app to `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`?

Comment: @yacine.b and is your app created by typing `manage.py startapp [app's name]`?